# Doubts while understanding why the Laplace transform is holomorphic?

Tags: complex-analysis, laplace-transform

I am trying to understand why the Laplace transform is holomorphic. Let's be more precise, let $\phi(w):\mathbb{R}^+\to\mathbb{C}$ be continuous. Let $A>0$ and $c\in\mathbb{R}$ such that
$$
|\phi(w)|\leq Ae^{cw}
$$
Consider now the Laplace transform of $\phi$ that I will call $\Phi$
$$
\Phi(z)=\int_0^{\infty}e^{-zw}\phi(w)\,dw
$$
We can easily show that the absolute value of the integral above is smaller than infinity in the domain $B_c=\{z\in\mathbb{C}:Re(z)>c\}$. Apparently you can prove that $\Phi(z)$ is holomorphic in B but I don't understand the steps given, which are the following. Because $|e^{-zw}|=e^{-wRe(z)}\leq e^{-c_1w}$ for $z\in B_d=\{z\in\mathbb{C}:Re(z)>d\}$ we can find $F:\mathbb{R}^+\to\mathbb{R}^+$ integrable and independent of $z$ such that $|e^{-zw}\phi(w)|\leq F(w)$ and deduce that $\Phi$ is holomorphic on $B_c$. I don't understand the last sentence. First, I would like more details on why we can fin an $F$ with the above properties, and why this guarantees the holomorphicity of $\Phi$.

Comment: @MyGlasses no, $w\in\mathbb{R}^+$

Answer (score 3):

[Morera's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morera's_theorem). Let be $\gamma\subset B_c$ a closed curve. Using Fubini (the line integral is an ordinary integral in some interval $[a,b]$) and the holomorphicity of $z\mapsto e^{-zw}\phi(w)$:

$$\int_{\gamma}\Phi(z)\,dz = \int_{\gamma}\int_0^{\infty}e^{-zw}\phi(w)\,dwdz = \int_0^{\infty}\int_{\gamma}e^{-zw}\phi(w)\,dzdw =  \int_0^{\infty}0\,dw = 0.$$

Comment: Why can we use Fubini's theorem? Did we show that the function is absolutely integrable on $ [a , b] \times (0, \infty)$ ?

Comment: Isn't that condition required for Reimann Integrals?  But the function is continuous and bounded on the region. This is enough, right?

Comment: @BokaPeer, as the domain is infinite, the Lebesgue version (Tonelli) is required. The absolute integrability is consequence of the bounding hypothesis on $\varphi$

Comment: Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

As you explained before, you have $$|e^{-zw}|=e^{-wRe(z)}\leq e^{-c_1w}.$$ Hence  $$|e^{-zw}\phi(w)|\leq e^{-c_1w} |\phi(w)| \leq Ae^{-c_1w}e^{cw}.$$ The $F$ you want is therefore given by $$F(w) = A e^{(c-c_1)w}.$$ It is integrable since $c_1 >c$ by construction. Now, why is $\Phi$ holomorphic. By definition, $\Phi$ is holomorphic if $$\frac{\partial \Phi}{\partial \overline{z}} =0.$$ Now we have to check the hypothesis to permute derivative and integral. Actually it will be essentially the same as what we did previously with $F$. So you can write $$\frac{\partial \Phi}{\partial \overline{z}} = \int_0^{\infty}\frac{\partial}{\partial \overline{z}}(e^{-zw}\phi(w))\,dw.$$ And of course this is equal to $0$ since $$\frac{\partial}{\partial \overline{z}}(e^{-zw})=0$$ by holomorphicity of the exponential.

Comment: Can you be more explicit on why you can commute derivative and integral?

Comment: Did you learn this theorem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule#Measure_theory_statement (in the case of the Lebesgue's measure) ?

Comment: Actually not, I am a physicist but I have learnt about lebesgue integrals but I am afraid I could be more fluent. In the theorem you quote, I see that some minor modifications would need to be done to apply it to this case. I would love to see the fully explicit thing if it is not to bothersome for you